# Post using anchor tag and append result to a div block [jQuery, ajax, spring mvc]

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I have an anchor tag inside a form through which I want to post a text to the controller, where it searches for an object (User) using the posted param (username).

Then I want to append the username to "#block-showusers". I have the following code so far, but it's not working.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <div id="block-addusers" class="form-group" style="display:none">
        <div id="block-showusers" style="height:25px;vertical-align:bottom"></div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="adduser" id="adduser"/>
            <a href="${SITE_URL}/user/search" id="btn-adduser" class="btn btn-default">
                Add
            </a>
            <button type="button" id="btn-canceladduser" class="btn btn-link">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
var usersBlock = "#block-addusers";
var userToAdd = "#adduser";
$("#btn-addusers").on('click', function () {
    $(usersBlock).show();
    $("#btn-adduser").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: '${SITE_URL}/user/search',
            data: {adduser: $(userToAdd).val()},
            success: function (data) {
                if (data !== "") {
                    $("#block-showusers").append('<div style="display:inline;margin-left:5px">' + data.username + '</div>');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The "search" method in my "/user" controller class:

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody User search(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "adduser") String addUser){
    return userDAO.getByUsername(addUser);
}
```

The "getByUsername" method:

```
public User getByUsername(String username) {
    session=sessionFactory.openSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.username=:username");
    query.setParameter("username", username);
    if (query.list().size() > 0) {
        session.close();
        return (User) query.uniqueResult();
    }
    session.close();
    return null;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated greatly. Thanks!

Comment: So, what doesn't work? Do you get a value in the string 'addUser' server side?

Comment: 'addUser' just has "adduser" as its value, and not whatever I input. Maybe that's to do with the `@RequestParam(defaultValue = "adduser")` part?

Comment: Hmm, maybe. Try removing it. And maybe there's one more problem. The  JS property 'adduser' in your AJAX data is not camelCased as your server side variable 'AddUser'. Try correcting that aswell.

Comment: If you want to send an object you have to use `@RequestBody` instead of `@RequestParam` and bind the parameter to an object.